# How to run console before login

Tags: command-line, drivers, gpu

How can I run console before login?

I cannot login for some reason.

Probably my integrated GPU on AMD Ryzen 7 7700X is not working with ubuntu.

I want to run console to be able to install drivers.

Or how can I run ubuntu in low graphic mode as I could do in instalation?

Answer (score 1):

Just start normally and press `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`F3` There you go, that's the terminal/command line.

[Source](https://www.makeuseof.com/fix-ubuntu-login-loop-issue/#:%7E:text=On%20these%20machines%2C%20you%20need,prompt%20in%20your%20home%20directory.)

Comment: Thanks, I can go to console now. But this article doesn't help. Every thing according it was set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

When grub is on screen press e and add `nomodeset` to the kernel boot parameters. That will skip the video card detection during boot.

Control-alt-f1 (or f2, f3, f4, f5, f6 (1 of these 6 will be your desktop)) to get a login. This is created by the video card driver so only works if the active driver works.You can press this pretty early just after grub.

On command line use `ubuntu-drivers devices` to install another driver version. `ubuntu-drivers --gpgpu devices` for graphics card drivers only.